# equivalence of matrices and the image

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was working on a problem and I would like to have someone give me an advice. The question was,

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n \times m$ matrices. Show that the $img(A)$ contains the $img(B)$ if and only if there is an $m \times m$ matrix $X$ so that $AX = B$.

My answer so far is if $A$ and $B$ are two matrices and if $X$ is a matrix so that $AX =B$, then $img(B)$ is contained in the $img(A)$ because $b \in img(B)$ if and only if there is a vector so that $By = b$ since $AX = B$, $b = By = (AX)y$

Does this make sense? Is there anyway to phrase better?

Comment: $b \subseteq img(B)$ seems wrong. Shouldn't it be $b \in \operatorname{Im} B$?

Comment: Also, note that you've only shown one side of the equivalence.

Comment: @VedranŠego yea, what was I thinking... thank you

Comment: @JonathanY Could you tell me how to start with the other side of the equivalence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose ${\cal R} B \subset  {\cal R} A$. Then for all $e_k$ (vector of zeroes with one in the $k$th position), there is some $x_k$ such that $A x_k = B e_k$, for $k=1,...,m$. Let $X = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & \cdots & x_m\end{bmatrix}$. Then $AX = \begin{bmatrix} B e_1 & \cdots & B e_m\end{bmatrix} = B$, as required.

Now suppose there is some $X$ such that $AX=B$. Clearly ${\cal R} B = {\cal R} (AX) \subset {\cal R} A$.

Comment: $\cal R$ is same as $img$ right?

Comment: Yes indeed, it is a standard symbol for 'range'. I am slow to change notation :-).

Comment: concisely explained, thank you for your help!